# How do I git merge a branch into itself

Tags: git, version-control, version

I have a branch that needs to be merged into itself. Is this possible to do in git, or should I use a different versioning system if this is going to be a normal case.

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding at the root of your question because it makes zero sense. What do you try to achieve? Or, what is [the problem](http://xyproblem.info/) you face that makes you think you'll solve it by "merging a branch into itself"?

Comment: Do you want to merge the local branch into remote branch, or merge the branch into its previous version?

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to have your current branch looking like you merged it with an ancestor (in the history of that branch, obviously, but just in case).... like, have master look like it was merged with master~5 on a new revision? I do it sometimes.

```
git checkout master~5
git merge master --no-ff -m "Here, a merge"
git branch -f master HEAD
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge into remote branch, just push it; If you want to merge into previous commits, you should create 2 branches from each version and try to merge these 2 branches.